# Can フラれて be used in any non-romantic sense?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Something like “shocked” or “deceived”. Or rejected by friend, not by lover. Or in the situation where the person ignored someone’s problem.

Really, any non-romantic meaning, even it’s not common.

Answer (score 3):

振られる/フラれる is *rejected/dumped*, not *shocked*. 私は彼を振った means "I dumped him", not "I shocked him". It does not directly describe someone's emotion.

This type of フる is basically only for romantic love, but you can still use 振られる, more or less figuratively or jokingly, to describe a rejection after expressing a non-romantic love. For example, it's possible to say 「あの会社に買収の提案をしたが、あっさり振られてしまったよ」. Jokingly saying 振られた once to your friend would be fine, but if you used it many times, your friend would start to wonder if you really have a romantic interest in him, so use this with caution.